# WebLogic JMS encryption

Tags: security, encryption, jms, weblogic, message-queue

How to encrypt the communication between nodes, which do messaging via distributed *WebLogic JMS broker*? Either transport level encryption, or even better end-to-end encryption, where the message itself is encrypted.

Does JMS provide out-of-the-box solution, or do I have to implement the security myself?

If I used SOAP over JMS to implement the end-to-end security with WS-Security, is it possible to configure the stack with pure Java EE, i.e. only WebLogic configurations and runtime libraries being used?

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, you don't have to reinvent the wheel to add transport level security to your JMS. Please refer to this [Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13159_01/osb/docs10gr3/security/transport_level.html#wp1078094).
Answering your second question, with a SOAP ws you can easily handle the end-to-end security but the performance and the overhead are way worse than using a queue.